# Bootstrap on rails form helper issue with date_field and select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to style my form in rails with bootstrap-4. But I'm having issues apply styles to the date_field helper and the select helper.

This is the date field. The class won't apply and throws an error until I take it off.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <%= form.label :appointment, :class => 'col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right' %>
    <div class="col-md-9">
         <%= date_field(:patient, :apointment), :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the select helper.
The options are appearing outside of the select box.

```
<div class="form-group row">
              <%= form.label :consultationType, :class => "col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right" %>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <select class ="form-control">
                  <!--Gets all counties from DB -->
                  <%= form.select :consultationType, 
                [
                    "N/A",
                    "Inhouse-Clinic",
                    "St.James Hospital - X-Ray",
                    "Matter Private Dublin - Cardiology",
                    "Matter Private Cork - Neurology",
                    "Royal Eye and Ear - Ophthalmology",
                    "Temple Street - Children"
                ] 
            %>
                </select>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Try giving the `class` inside the brackets: `date_field(:patient, :appointment,  class: 'form-control')`

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following

```
<%= date_field(:patient, :apointment, class: "form-control") %>
```

Generated HTML

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="patient[apointment]" id="patient_apointment">
```

And for the select tag, you have declared two times, you can remove the HTML `<select>` tag and then add the bootstrap class like this

```
<%= form.select :consultationType,
    [
        "N/A",
        "Inhouse-Clinic",
        "St.James Hospital - X-Ray",
        "Matter Private Dublin - Cardiology",
        "Matter Private Cork - Neurology",
        "Royal Eye and Ear - Ophthalmology",
        "Temple Street - Children"
    ], {}, {class: "form-control"} 
%>
```

Generated HTML like this

```
<select class="form-control" name="patient[consultationType]" id="model_consultationType"><option value="N/A">N/A</option>
    <option value="Inhouse-Clinic">Inhouse-Clinic</option>
    <option value="St.James Hospital - X-Ray">St.James Hospital - X-Ray</option>
    <option value="Matter Private Dublin - Cardiology">Matter Private Dublin - Cardiology</option>
    <option value="Matter Private Cork - Neurology">Matter Private Cork - Neurology</option>
    <option value="Royal Eye and Ear - Ophthalmology">Royal Eye and Ear - Ophthalmology</option>
    <option value="Temple Street - Children">Temple Street - Children</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `date_field` move the class inside the brackets:

```
date_field(:patient, :appointment, class: 'form-control')
```

And for the `select` it is not required to give HTML select tag explicitly. Just doing like this will do the job:

```
<%= form.select :consultationType, ["N/A", "Inhouse-Clinic", "St.James Hospital - X-Ray", "Matter Private Dublin - Cardiology", "Matter Private Cork - Neurology", "Royal Eye and Ear - Ophthalmology", "Temple Street - Children"], {}, { class: 'form-control' }  %>
```